# Are there premade particles to add to a scene?

Tags: particles

Is it possible to find premade particles like:

Snow 
Rain: drops, window deposit, storm 
Blizzard 
Fog 
Kicked up dust 
Fire: camp, torch, forest 
Smoke from: exhaust, stack, fire  
Breath 
Tornado 
Clouds 
Waterfall 
Sparks

Just import, adjust, customize and use?
These are so common they should be available as an addon... I hope.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/YQk8nXloVftzW/giphy.gif As far as I know there isn't such thing. Also things like snow, fire, waterfall are often made with completely different solvers. Another thing is that this question doesn't look like it belongs on BSE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about searching an add-on not problem within Blender itself.

Comment: @LukeD There are preset fluid thicknesses so surely it's a legitimate question to ask if there are particle presets, regardless of whether the answer is to suggest an add-on?

Comment: @RayMairlot Viscosity presets (Water, Honey, Oil) vs Rain: drops, window deposit, storm, waterfall (all water)? Sticking to the latter, how to make waterfall preset? What should be the options? Making presets for particles could be possible but not for the most of listed examples.

Comment: @LukeD Well, there's things like quick smoke, but that's not really the point. They're not asking us to find an add-on they know about, they're asking if such presets exist in Blender or otherwise. Just because someone mentions that they think such a feature might be in an add-on, the question is suddenly off-topic? Q: "I want to mirror a mesh, hopefully an add-on does this." A: "You don't need an add-on, that's built into Blender." My point is, why is asking if Blender (or an add-on) has these presets (which is possible) off-topic?

Comment: @RayMairlot "Is it possible to find premade particles like: (...)" are not presets. For me this is equivalent to "Is it possible to find an animal models like: dog, cat, goose, elk". Moreover, provided examples emphasizes my point. We have presets (in Cloth sim) for Silk, Leather and so on (same thing in Fluid sim), but we don't have presets for jacket, t-shirt or trousers. For most of provided examples you will need a whole scene setup (mesh, force field, obstacles etc.), not only presets for chosen solver.

Comment: @LukeD Yes, in Blender, these types of presets might not be possible due to the complexity. But these types of presets are possible in other software (Maya: Effects Assets) and that's why I think it's a valid question to ask if they're possible in Blender.

Comment: I totally agree with validity over "is it possible to create". Maybe a little bit too broad but still ok with me. But in this case we have "is it possible to find" and yes, it is possible to find those effects on blenderartists, blender market, youtube, maybe even here on BSE (I've myself answered to couple particle effects questions). But overall this question seems to me (and some other users) as more suited for search engine than BSE.